# How to connect a ThinkPad laptop to an incompatible (?) ThinkPad dock?

Tags: thinkpad, docking-station

I have a ThinkPad branded docking station and a ThinkPad T470 laptop that fits it (see picture). I connect the laptop by putting it onto the docking station and gently pressing it in. This works perfectly well.

[image]

Now, I have another model of ThinkPad laptop* that does not have the connectors on its bottom. Thus, it is physically impossible to connect the laptop to the docking station by placing the laptop on top and pressing it in.

Is there any way of connecting such a laptop (a different one than pictured above) to the docking station?

<sub>*Actually, there are several laptops that I would like to be able to connect: T420, T530, X1 Carbon 4th Gen and X1 Carbon 5th Gen.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple: No.

The bottom connector that mates up to the docking-station is specific to a range off motherboards and matching docking stations. If they don't match there is no way to use it.

You mention the T420 and T530, if I recall correctly both use the older style dock, while the T440 and later (like your T470) use the newer dock. The X-series uses a different dock that also comes in an old and new versions.
The X1 series are altogether different beasts using Thunderbolt based docks. (The T480, T580 and later models also have Thunderbolt.) These can be used with a specific Thinkpad docks for that model or with a generic dock using the Thunderbolt port.

If you really need to be able to connect a wide range of laptops to a minimum number of docks your best bet is to have 3:

- A generic USB 3 dock (that can also be used with USB 2.0) with a type A connector for older laptops that only have USB. (On USB 2.0 the video-outputs on the dock will probably don't work or be to slow to be usable.)
- A generic USB-C dock for those laptops that have USB-C.
- A generic Thunderbolt dock for those laptops that have Thunderbolt. (Please note that many Thunderbolt laptops have the TB on USB-C connectors. That doesn't mean they work with a USB-C dock!)

Another cave-at: USB/USB-C docks typically use DisplayLink technology/drivers for the video-outputs on the dock. This may be problematic with a Thunderbolt laptop. In many cases the Displaylink drivers and the Thunderbolt drivers (even if no Thunderbolt device is connected) together on the same laptop don't mix well and may cause display-driver crashes or even blue screens.

Comment: I have just checked, and unfortunately, X1 Carbon 4th Gen does not have a Thunderbolt port.

Comment: There are Lenovo USB Hubs you can use for this purpose.